# How to remove default Bluehost favicon in library file window

Tags: wordpress, favicon, bluehost, media-library

I'm a new Wordpress user and I used the 'All in one Favicon' plugin to replace the default Favicon of my host, Bluehost. This works on my website, but I have a few links to media library files, and when I open those, the Bluehost favicon returns. How do I remove it?

My website: http://dominiqueblok.org (the relevant links are under 'Work', e.g. http://www.dominiqueblok.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Abstract-DGFS-3.pdf)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a manual from wordpress website:

1. Go to your WordPress Administration Panel.
2. Click on Appearance.
3. Click on Theme Editor.
4. Select the file called Header or header.php to edit the file.
5. Search for the line of code that begins with  `<link rel="shortcut icon" and ends with /favicon.ico" />.`
6. Overwrite it, if it exists, or add the following code below the `<head>` HTML tag.
   `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />`

[WORDPRESS URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Favicon)

Comment: Many thanks for your response! I'm using a child theme, so I did the following:

- copied the original theme's header.php file into my child theme folder
- put the favicon.ico file in my child theme folder (it was already in my main directory)
- tried to find the <link ... .ico" /> code in the .php file but didn't
- copied the new code right below <head>
- manually replaced all Bluehost favicon files in my directory by the blank favicon
- emptied my cache.

The Bluehost favicon is still there. Do you have any idea what else I could do? Thank you in advance!